# Minterms from Logic Circuit

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have the following logic circuit:

[image]

And I'm asked to identify the minterms in F's truth table.

The expression for F is

F = C + A'B'

and the truth table isn't too difficult to construct (X=F):

[image]

I said that the minterms are m0, m1, m3, m5, and m7, as F is 1 in rows 0, 1, 3, 5, and 7 of the truth table above.

But the textbook says that the answer is m0, m1, m2, m3, m6, m7. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sometimes textbooks have mistakes.

Comment: @ThePhoton Indeed, hence why some of them have more than one edition :)

Comment: Missing the published error corrections perhaps added to appendix of the next version or maybe Prof's are using local Ref Books with errors

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will mention it to the instructor since this is in the exam review and the incorrect solution is used in the answer key.